# Bind value from foreign key?

Tags: c#, blazor

```
<select class="form-select"  
    @bind-value="lowesCreditsViewModels.CreditStatusId" 
    @bind-value:event="oninput"  
    @onchange="OnSaveCreditStatus">

@foreach (var pO in this.SharedPageModel.CreditStatusViewModels)
{
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="@pO.Id">@pO.StatusName</option>
}
</select>

private async Task OnSaveCreditStatus()
{
    if (lowesCreditsViewModels.CreditStatusName == "Paid")
    {
        IsRefundDateDisabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        IsRefundDateDisabled = true;
    }

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

In `OnSaveCreditStatus` method I need to compare if creditstatus is "Paid"  then make refund date field editable. I dont want to compare against Id. Is there any way to bind statusname ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="mb-3">
    <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value:get=_selectedId @bind-Value:set=OnSelected>
        @if(_selectedId is null)
        {
            <option disabled selected value="null"> - Select a Value - </option>
        }
        @foreach(var option in Items)
        {
            <option value="@option.Id">@option.Name</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Id : @_selectedId</pre>
    <pre>Name : @_selectedName</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid? _selectedId;
    private string? _selectedName;

    public List<FxKeyPair> Items = new List<FxKeyPair>()
    {
        new FxKeyPair(Guid.NewGuid(), "France"), 
        new FxKeyPair(Guid.NewGuid(), "Germany"),
        new FxKeyPair(Guid.NewGuid(), "UK"),
        new FxKeyPair(Guid.NewGuid(), "Spain"),
    };

    private Task OnSelected(Guid? value)
    {
        _selectedId = value;
        if (value is not null)
            _selectedName = this.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id.Equals(value))?.Name ?? null;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public record FxKeyPair(Guid Id, string Name);
}
```